# Cannot declare function twice

Tags: functions

I have two hooks that i am using in the code snippets plugin:

1.

```php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
       
    function businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
      
    
     $shipping_class_target = '1173'; // This is Deluxe Tables shipping class ID 
       $in_cart = false;
       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
          if ( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
             $in_cart = true;
             break;
          } 
       }
       if ( $in_cart ) {
          unset( $rates['local_pickup:45'] ); // This is Local Pick up shipping method with ID 
       }
       return $rates;
    }
```

2. 

```php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
       
    function businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
      
       $shipping_class_target = '1750'; // This is Stag & Doe shipping class ID 
       $in_cart = false;
       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
          if ( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
             $in_cart = true;
             break;
          } 
       }
       if ( $in_cart ) {
          unset( $rates['WB_Custom_WooCommerce_Shipping_Method52'] ); // This is Delivery shipping method with ID 
       }
       return $rates;
    
    
    }
```

If only one is activated at a time it works!  But it says I cannot declare the function twice, so how do I combine these two?  I have tried so many variations and nothing is working.  Please help!

Comment: PHP can't have two functions with identical names. Rename one of your functions and you should be OK.

Comment: They can't have the same name, you need to rename one of them

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Pat in the comments: the easiest thing to do would be to rename the function in one of the two snippets, changing the name both on the function definition and the add_filter line. But if you did want to combine the two into a single snippet you could do something like this:

```php
function businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    $deluxe_tables_shipping_class_target = '1173';
    $stag_and_doe_shipping_class_target = '1750';

    $hide_local_pickup = false;
    $hide_delivery_shipping = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        $shipping_class_id = $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id();
        if ( $deluxe_tables_shipping_class_target == $shipping_class_id ) {
            $hide_local_pickup = true;
        } elseif ( $stag_and_doe_shipping_class_target == $shipping_class_id ) {
            $hide_delivery_shipping = true;
        }
    }
    if ( $hide_local_pickup ) {
        // This is Local Pick up shipping method with ID
        unset( $rates['local_pickup:45'] );
    }
    if ( $hide_delivery_shipping ) {
        // This is Delivery shipping method with ID
        unset( $rates['WB_Custom_WooCommerce_Shipping_Method52'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates',
            'businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
```

(You could also change the code to use === in the two `== $shipping_class_id` lines but I don't know if WooCommerce stores that ID as a string or a number, so == is safer.)